# Como criar um calendário múltiplo, apenas com ano e mês?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-3, jquery-ui, datepicker

Estou utilizando o Boostrap 4.1.1 e estou tentando criar um calendário múltiplo apenas com o mês e o ano, igual o da imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No momento o meu calendário está deste modo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**CÓDIGO:**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control border-0" id="periodo-picker" placeholder="Período">

    <script>
    $('#periodo-picker').datepicker( {
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        dateFormat: 'mm/yy',
        onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
            $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, 1));
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Já fiz isso em outras perguntas, mas faço novamente, recomendo que leia: [**Como devemos formatar perguntas e respostas?**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1084/28595)

Comment: Dá uma olhada no [Datepicker for Bootstrap](https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=mm-yyyy&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=1&minViewMode=0&maxViewMode=4&todayBtn=false&clearBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox)

Comment: Nesse link você pode testar os formatos, em *"Start View"*, selecione *"1/ months"*